# Кавычки в словосочетании Донбасс Арена

Tags: орфография

Правильно писать название стадиона в кавычках и без дефиса? Или дефис всё же нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Дефис нужен, потому что это сложное слово с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в им. п. ед. ч. с нулевым окончанием, например: *допинг-контроль, жар-птица, интернет-проект* (об этом можно прочитать в Правилах орфографии и пунктуации по ред. В.В.Лопатина). Кавычки тоже нужны (см. Розенталь Д.Э. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, §129). Так что правильное написание - **"Донбасс-Арена"**.